# Adding soap faults without changing WSDL file?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, soapfault

I would like to add some SOAP Faults to my JAX-WS web service, but I would like not to change content of WSDL schema. As far as I read I would have to use annotation @WebFault to define SOAP Fault and it automatically causes changes in WSDL during next build. Is there any way to use SOAP Faults without changing content of WSDL scheme?

Answer (score 2):

When you throw an Exception from your code it will be automatically mapped to a SOAP fault by JAX-WS in the response. There's no need to define a fault in your WSDL.

Using `@WebFault` or defining a `<soap:fault>` element in the WSDL file is used to declare that a specific operation might return a custom SOAP fault.

`@WebFault` will definitely add a `<soap:fault>` element in the resulting WSDL.

To recap, throwing an Exception will insert a  element in the soap response.

**Update**

**Custom faultstring:**

The string message that you pass as a parameter to the `Exception` constructor represents the faultstring element in the `<soap:fault>`. Example:

```
throw new Exception("This is the faultstring text");
```

Resulting fault in the soap response:

```
<soap:fault>
    <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
    <faultstring>This is the faultstring text</faultstring>
</soap:fault>
```

**Custom faultcode:**

I don't think you can change the faultcode with normal Java exceptions. If you really need to do that you can take a look at JAX-WS [SOAPFaultException](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jaxws-api/2.2/javax/xml/ws/soap/SOAPFaultException.html).

Keep in mind that faultcodes are used to indicate the type of error produced, and most of the time you are going to return a Server fault from your webservice.

This are the four existing fault codes in SOAP 1.1 and 1.2:

- **VersionMismatch**: Found an invalid namespace for the SOAP Envelope element.
- **MustUnderstand**: An immediate child element of the Header element, with the mustUnderstand attribute set to "1", was not understood.
- **Client**: The message was incorrectly formed or contained incorrect information.
- **Server**: There was a problem with the server so the message could not proceed.

The first three are going to be created by JAX-WS when parsing the SOAP request and unless there's a very specific situation or you are writing your own JAX-WS handlers/interceptors you will not need to return any other faultcode besides 'Server'.

**Custom detail:**

The `<detail>` element will be populated with an element representing the Exception. For example if you are throwing a `new MyCustomException("custom message")` it will be something like this:

```
<detail>
    <MyCustomException>
        <message>custom message</message>
    </MyCustomException>
</detail>
```

Comment: Ok, but what if I want to change faultcode and faultstring?

Comment: I updated the answer. You can customize faultstring but not faultcode with java Exceptions.

Comment: If I throw checked exception then I have to change signature of my webmethod by adding "throws" clause and therefore I would have to change interface of my web method so it is not possible to just throw checked exceptions without making big changes in web service interface. As I've found I have to throw unchecked exception in that case. But when I throw RuntimeException it still doesn't work as expected, I throw unchecked exception "throw new RuntimeException("test");" and faultstring is "Internal Error" instead of "test". Any ideas?

Comment: I am using Axis framework to cope with SOAP messages and it seems like AxisFault overrides my SOAP Fault http://pastebin.com/4Dkv4Qh6

Comment: Well this is getting tricky, I never liked Axis. So you need to throw an unchecked exception and that when Axis wraps it into an AxisFault it does not override the message... When you throw a checked exception I think Axis wraps it anyway in an AxisFault but it does not override the message. Then I would try with another type of unchecked exception and hope that Axis logic does not override the message for that one. Try with Error class: "throw new Error("test");" and see how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunately effect is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Test your web service using Soap Ui. I just tested mine, using a custom message in the exception and when I see the Response from Soap Ui, I see that the Fault String has my custom Message.