# Throw SOAP Fault not mentioned in WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, soapfault

I am using contract first approach to publish a web service using JAX-WS. There are no SOAP fault in the WSDL, but the existing web service throws fault exceptions appropriately.

I am unable to throw similar fault exception as the service method I am implementing now asks to add throws clause.

I could find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588138/adding-soap-faults-without-changing-wsdl-file) as related one.

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Perhaps you can add some example code to clarify things?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you are asking how to add the thrown exception to your wsdl?

There are a few reasons why a thrown exception doesn't show up in a generated wsdl

1. The thrown exception is not a checked exception, for example because you subclassed it from a RuntimeException which is an unchecked exception.
2. You did not add `throws MyException` to your webservice method (you caught the exception instead).
3. Some people say that you have to add the [`@WebFault` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/WebFault.html) to your exception class, but in my experience this isn't required (perhaps it depends on the jax-ws version you use).

Comment: It was the first case for me. Odd enough, when using cxf as webservices implementation it was okay to use unchecked exceptions. Had to convert my exceptions to checked ones after switching to JAX-WS RI.